# Kivy ~ AttributeError: 'TextInput' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, user-interface, attributes, kivy, yfinance

I have been messing around with python kivy and I have stumbled on the error as given in the title. I am trying to print the stock price of an arbirtary stock by using the yfinance package through kivy. I get the error:AttributeError: 'TextInput' object has no attribute 'replace'. Does any of you have a clue what I am doing wrong here:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
import yfinance as yf 
import numpy as np
   

    
class MyStock(FloatLayout):
    
    enterticker = ObjectProperty(None)
    enterstartdate = ObjectProperty(None)
    enterenddate = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def DownloadStockData(self, ticker, starting, ending):

        Download = yf.download(ticker, start = starting, end = ending)
        StockData1 = Download["Close"]        
        StockValue = [0]*len(StockData1)
    
        for i in range(len(StockValue)):
            StockValue[i] = StockData1[i]
            
        
        return StockValue   

    def btn(self):        
        self.stockvalue.text = self.DownloadStockData(self.enterticker, self.enterstartdate, self.enterenddate)                        
        print(self.enterticker.text, self.enterstartdate.text, self.enterenddate.text, self.stockvalue.text)
    

class FinancialDashboard(App):    
     def build(self):
         Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
         return MyStock()
   
                   
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    FinancialDashboard().run()
```

and my kivy file:

```
<MyStock>:

    enterticker: enterticker
    enterstartdate: enterstartdate
    enterenddate: enterenddate
        

    FloatLayout:
        
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.41, "y":0.9}
            text: "Confirm" 
            font_size:14
            color:0, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint:0.2, 0.1
            background_color:0.9, 0.9, 0.9,1
            on_press: root.btn()     
            
            
                        
            
        Label:
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "y":0.9}
            text: "Enter ticker"
            size_hint:0.2, 0.1
            
        TextInput:
            id: enterticker                 
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.19, "y":0.9}
            multiline:False
            size_hint:0.2, 0.1
            
            
        Label:
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "y":0.8}
            text: "Enter Start Date "
            size_hint:0.2, 0.1
            
        TextInput:
            id: enterstartdate                    
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.19, "y":0.8}
            multiline:False
            size_hint:0.2, 0.1


        Label:
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "y":0.7}
            text: "Enter End Date "
            size_hint:0.2, 0.1
            
        TextInput:
            id: enterenddate                 
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.19, "y":0.7}
            multiline:False
            size_hint:0.2, 0.1
            
            
            

        Label:
            color:0, 0, 0, 1
            pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "y":0.6}
            text: "stockvalue"
            size_hint:0.2, 0.1
```

with the error message:

```
   File "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Python xxxx\OneDrive-2021-02-26\StockGUI.py", line 22, in DownloadStockData
     Download = yf.download(ticker, start = starting, end = ending)
   File "C:\Users\xxxx\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 71, in download
     tickers, (list, set, tuple)) else tickers.replace(',', ' ').split()
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'TextInput' object has no attribute 'replace
```

'

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your error text clearly indicates that you're passing a `TextInput` object to something that expects to receive a string.

The culprit is then presumably:

```
self.stockvalue.text = self.DownloadStockData(self.enterticker, self.enterstartdate, self.enterenddate)
```

You likely want instead:

self.stockvalue.text = self.DownloadStockData(self.enterticker.text, self.enterstartdate.text, self.enterenddate.text)

Comment: Thank you, it works now.I thought already it had to do with it expecting a string, but your solution did not cross my mind. Cheers ;)